# Add Javascript File To Head For Create Block

Tags: module, javascript, magento-1, blocks

I need to create a block programatically (for various reasons):

```
$myblock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace_module/path', 'my_block', $params);
```

This works fine, but the controller action is skipped over when doing this. I mean, it is, right? Therefore, my XML **layout** file is ignored, which contains:

file: `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/namespace_module.xml`

```
<layout>
    ...
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>namespace_module/script.min.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
    ...
</layout>
```

I have tried adding the JS file programmatically as follows, but I get nothing at all:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('namespace_module/script.min.js');
```

I will also need to reference the CSS file. It's late, so this could be a stupid error. Any guidance/advice welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The layout and blocks are kind of in a 'one direction' relation. I mean you can reference blocks in the layout but you cannot load layout files when creating an instance of a block. Actually you could but it's not the best idea to do so. Layouts should be called by the controllers.
When manually creating an instance of a block it has nothing to do with the layout files.
As for the second part, adding a js to the head, you have the right idea. It's done like you tried:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('js/path/here.js');
```

BUT... If the `head` block is already rendered then it has no effect. You have to make sure the js is added to the head after `loadLayout()` has been called in the controller action and before you call `renderLayout()` in the same action.

Comment: Once again Marius, thx so much

Comment: This method won't work on block type `Mage_Core_Block_Template`. I could be doing something wrong, ofc! I'm calling it in the `_prepareLayout` method between the load and render layouts.

Comment: Work for me very useful thx Marius