# How can I include JS/CSS files only on pages which have my widget?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, blocks, widgets

I'm creating a custom widget of a form element which requires some CSS and Javascript. I plan on injecting the CSS and Javascript files into the `<head>` section of any pages which uses that widget.

So what I did was I used the `addJs()` method within the `_prepareLayout()` method in my Block class:

```
class TestSpace_MyWidget_Block_Widget_TestWidget extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('mywidget/script.js');
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function _toHtml()
    {
        return "Testing widget";
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to put that Javascript file into the `<head>` section.

I'm not putting my widget through the CMS or admin panel. My widget is placed in a few other templates (a phtml file) of the site like so:

```
$widget = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mywidget/testwidget');
$widget->toHtml();
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't work since nothing should be rendered on the page yet at this point, right?

I'm aware that I can define my Javascript in a Layout file, but I'm avoiding doing so because that would mean I would either have to put that Javascript file in every single pages or hard code those pages that I want to include my JS file.

How can I include JS or CSS files in the `<head>` section only on pages which have my widget?

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891335/how-can-add-css-file-to-custom-widget-in-magento/21109065

Comment: @AshishMadankar I'm not putting my widget through the CMS or admin panel. I placed the widget in a phtml template file. So it's slightly different from the case in that link you had posted. I've updated my question to show how my widget was put into the template.

Comment: If the head block is already rendered then it has no effect. You have to make sure the js is added to the head after loadLayout() has been called in the controller action and before you call renderLayout() in the same action.  Refer to marius answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/add-javascript-file-to-head-for-create-block

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Is there a way to check if my widget was called between `loadLayout()` and `renderLayout()`?

Comment: Can you add your full block code plez.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I've updated my question with my full block code.

Comment: I would suggest to call `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('mywidget/script.js');` in those template files where you are calling your `$widget->toHtml();`

Comment: @AdarshKhatri oh... the `toHtml()` actually gets called between `loadLayout()` and `renderLayout()` but not for `_prepareLayout()`?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I just tried calling `$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('mywidget/script.js');` in the template files, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you guys find a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="<?php echo $block->getAssetUrl('Webbazaar_CallCssDemo::css/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

namespace Webbazaar\CallCssDemo\Block;

```
namespace Webbazaar\CallCssDemo\Block;
```

Block Demo.php
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
class Demomanager extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

```
//This function will be used to get the css/js file.
function getAssetUrl($asset) {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $assetRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository');
    return $assetRepository->createAsset($asset)->getUrl();
}
```

}