# In Magento 2, what is the best practice for loading some CSS for a custom widget, so that the stylesheet only loads when the widget is present?

Tags: magento2, css, widgets

I have created a Magento 2 widget that displays a list of categories, similar to the one shown in [this guide](https://www.classyllama.com/blog/creating-a-custom-widget-in-magento-2). The widget outputs the correct HTML, so now I need to add some styling to it to make it look nice.

In my reading on the internet, I have found that I can tell Magento to load a CSS file

1. under the `default` layout file, which I presume will make it appear on all pages, or
2. in a layout file that is specific to a single layout handle (for example, `catalog_product_view`).

What I am not understanding is **how I can tell Magento to *ONLY* load that CSS file if the widget is present on a given page**. Obviously, I can simply hard-code the path to a CSS file in the widget template itself, but this seems hacky. It would also mean that Magento has no way to know to compile/minify that CSS file.

I found [a similar question about Magento 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121031/how-can-i-include-js-css-files-only-on-pages-which-have-my-widget), but the only answer is suggesting to do the exact thing I want to avoid: Having to hard-code the CSS include in the template file.

Disclaimer: Some of my assumptions may be incorrect, so feel free to correct me accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: No, sorry. In the 4 years since I posted this, I've abandoned Magento entirely and now use Shopify as my platform of choice for new builds.

Answer (score 0):

Within your custom widget module create the following file:

```
view/frontend/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Add the following code to _extend.less:

```
@import 'widget/example.less';
```

Create your .less file here:

```
view/frontend/web/css/source/widget/example.less
```